# How to reload page after using fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Was wondering why my code below isnt working. Basically I am fetch data from my url to delete something. on delete, it should refresh. however it doesnt seem to let me do that. But what it does is delete the post if i manually refresh the page.

Works when I use Ajax method though which I don't know why.

Fetch method

```js
const deleteBTN = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteBtn');
const update = document.querySelectorAll('.postedNote');

console.log(deleteBTN);

for (let btn of deleteBTN) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("Delete from front end");
        console.log(btn[btn])
        let id = e.target.dataset.btn;
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/notes' + '/' + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
        }).then(() => {
            Location: reload()
        })
    })
}
```

Ajax method

```js
$(".deleteBtn").click((e) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/api/notes/${e.target.dataset.btn}`,
        success: function () {
            console.log("delete success");
        },
    }).done(
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.reload();
        }, 500)
    );
});
```

Comment: What if you use `window.location.reload();` instead of `Location: reload()` in case of fetch too?

Comment: I've tried adding that, but it simply doesn't reach the .then() method at all

Comment: Do you really need reload? On successful request you can simply delete the element by manipulate DOM. Reloading the whole page seems like dirty solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can reload by using window.location.reload as already doing on ajax success.

Kindly find below as code snippet

```
const deleteBTN = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteBtn');
const update = document.querySelectorAll('.postedNote');

console.log(deleteBTN);



for (let btn of deleteBTN) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("Delete from front end");
        console.log(btn[btn])
        let id = e.target.dataset.btn;
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/notes' + '/' + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
        }).then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
        })
    })
}
```

Also, a few considerations below
The use of Ajax is defeated here as we are reloading the page.
Either

- we should perform some DOM manipulation to delete the deleted post
  from the page

Or,

- in case we are using React, we can bind posts to state and then
  delete the deleted post on API success call, so that component is
  re-rendered and we do not need to refresh the page.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your message. I tried the method above. 

this is the error is get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

the ajax method works for some reason. but the fetch method is returning errors. however if i refresh it would delete the post

Comment: Hi, Kindly try with below code and know the feeback
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/notes' + '/' + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
        }).then((res) => {
            res.json()
        }).then(res => window.location.reload())

Comment: Kindly put a catch block to see if rest call is passing or failing at moment.

Comment: it returned a TypeError: Failed to fetch message.

Comment: I believe backend is throwing this error, once API response is success it should work

Comment: Tried this method but not working either

Comment: @Mehdi, can you please add your sample code here?

Comment: @Hemant sorry it was my mistake fetch was not working using('localhost..) now after some tries it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should'nt try to reload the page when removing one of the elements,
instead I would have checked the response status and manually update the DOM to make the deleted element disappear if response says it was removed successfully.